# in a triangle $ABC,$ if $2c^2=a^2+b^2,$ then largest possible degree measure of angle $C$ is

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle $ABC,$ if $2c^2=a^2+b^2,$ then largest possible degree measure of angle $C$ is

cosine formula $\displaystyle \cos C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} = \frac{c^2}{2ab}<\frac{(a+b)^2}{2ab}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}+1$

wan,t be able to process after that, could some help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos{C}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{4ab}\ge\dfrac{1}{2}$$
so
$$C\le \dfrac{\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $a=p-q,b=p+q,c^2=p^2+q^2$

$\cos C=\cdots=\dfrac{c^2}{2ab}=\dfrac12+\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2(p^2-q^2)}-\dfrac12\ge\dfrac12$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$\cos C =\frac {a^2+b^2-c^2 }{2ab} =\frac {c^2}{2ab} =\frac {a^2+b^2}{4ab} $$ Now applying the AM-GM inequality, we get, $$\frac {a^2+b^2}{4ab}\geq \frac {1}{2} \Rightarrow C\leq \frac {\pi}{3} $$ Hope it helps.